# Which type of sum of squares corresponds to the partition of variance formula for two-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, variance, sums-of-squares, partitioning

Does anyone have a good reference for the formula for type I and type III sum of squares in two-way ANOVA?

I learned the following formula for partition of total sum of squares in two-way ANOVA. Is it correct? If so, which type of sum of squares does it refer to? It does not look like type I or type III to me. Confused.

[image]

Comment: If $SS_A$ is great so the way $A$ is significant and so on until $AB$, if $SSE$ is very great so the response doesn't change due to a factor lying or combination between both factors.

Comment: I later realize the formula is only for balanced design. Under balanced design, all types of sum squares are the same.

Comment: There is almost no difference between unbalanced's design and balanced, the formula would hold to. The only difference is $n$ will be $n_{ijk}$ or something like this.